# Trouble Waking Up for Emergencies (On-Call)

Tags: work-environment

I have noticed that when I sleep, approximately every two hours I enter a sleep phase where I am virtually unresponsive to any noise. (Alarms on max settings blaring for 10 minutes don't rouse me)

Is it reasonable to ask to be called multiple times, half-hours apart?

Are there any tricks I can apply so that I can reliably wake up when the phone rings, or should I just not take jobs with on-call?

Comment: Seems like waking up fast in those kinds of jobs is a *must* if you are going to take them IMO...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not [lifehacks.se] and we don't know what response time is required in your company for being on call (although it seems unlikely that asking to be called multiple times would go over well).

Comment: If you can't be reliably woken in an emergency, then you cannot be trusted in an emergency.  You should really take yourself off that roster.

Comment: How to wake up in case of an emergency call is not a workplace issue, it roughly falls into personal productivity if you stretch the definition of productivity a bit. Whether you should take this job or not is a personal decision that only you can make. In general though, you should avoid taking jobs that you can only do with great difficulty. For example, if I have a weak body, I should probably avoid doing any jobs that require heavy lifting or other physical labour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm hearing impaired, so I know all about this.  Set your mobile phone to vibrate and put it under your pillow.

Failing that, you'll need to get in touch with your local support group for the deaf and ask about vibrating devices.  Tell them that you need to be able to awaken for an emergency call and see what they suggest.

Comment: Jokes aside, or receive some sort of mild electric shock. Or have someone wake you up by shaking you, if possible.

Comment: Some other stimuli may trigger you much better.  For me, water to the face is gonna wake me up.

Comment: This might not be relevant to the OP, but hearing impairment probably (depending on location) constitutes a (mild) disability that the company would be expected to accommodate. Asking for multiple calls seems fairly reasonable.

Comment: For me, a vibrating device (a fitness band in my case) worked only for a few days. Now, it's been vibrating for months in the morning and I no longer feel it. You might consider that before investing any money into it.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Genius idea.

Comment: @mbrig, I'm not sure that making the company wait for multiple half hour delays in an"emergency" is reasonable